# jQuery load giving me more than I need

Tags: jquery

I am sending the following variable to the jQuery load method, expecting only the hash-tagged 'div' in return, instead I am getting the whole site:

url: http://localhost/createstudios/videos/?vimeo=15741581#sidebar

function:

```
   function mf_ajax_load_new_content(url, div){
            //$('#ajax_loader').clone().prependTo('#main-content-area').show();
            $(div).animate({opacity:0.1},500,function(){
                $(this).children().remove();

                $(this).parent().load(url+div, function() {
                    $(this).animate({opacity:1},500);
                });
            })
    }

mf_ajax_load_new_content($(this).attr('href'), "#sidebar");
```

Comment: if the serverside script does'nt return what's expected, you better show the serverside code.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. Works without javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space in there, like this:

```
$(this).parent().load(url+" "+div, function() {
```

Without the space you're getting `"page.html#sidebar"` which isn't the `"url selector"` format you're after, the hash is completely discarded.  Add the space to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

try
`mf_ajax_load_new_content($(this).attr('href'), " #sidebar");`

I believe you need that space.
Also your url won't help us as it is on your localhost :)

Comment: yeah, only put the URL up to show it's form. No need to actually use it.